# How to change fragment when a onClick event is triggerred?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to change from `HomeFragment` to `AperoDetailFragment` when I click on a list item in this `HomeFragment`.

I can already trigger the event and it seems to work since the logs appears. This is my `HomeFragment`:

```java
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    private View root;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater,
                             final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });

        ArrayList<AperoVersion> incomingApero = new ArrayList<AperoVersion>();
        initList(incomingApero);
        AperoIncomingAdapter adapterIncomingApero = new AperoIncomingAdapter(this.getContext(),R.layout.apero_coming_cell_layout, incomingApero);
        final ListView listIncomingApero = (ListView)root.findViewById(R.id.list_apero);
        listIncomingApero.setAdapter(adapterIncomingApero);
        listIncomingApero.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
                AperoVersion selectedItem = (AperoVersion) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Log.v("Root now", "Root: " + root);

                //root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.apero_detail_layout, container, false);
                Fragment newFragment = new AperoDetailFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.list_apero, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();

                Log.v("CustomAdapterExemple", "Selected element: " + selectedItem.getName());
                Log.v("Root now", "Root: " + root);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
```

I tried with the `root = inflater...` and the root changed in the log but the display wasn't changing. Then I tried with the transaction but I get the error:

```
2020-03-02 21:23:41.401 6781-6781/com.example.lapero E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.lapero, PID: 6781
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
        at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:489)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:326)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2169)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1992)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1947)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

I can provide any xml file if needed. So how can I change my displayed layout/fragment ?

[edit]
Here is my AperoDetailFragment.java :

```java
public class AperoDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private View root;

    public AperoDetailFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater,
                             final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_apero, container, false);

        //------------------------------------- la liste simple des apéros à venir-------------------
        ArrayList<AperoVersion> aperoList = new ArrayList<AperoVersion>();
        initList(aperoList);
    //    AperoAdapter adapter = new AperoAdapter(this.getContext(),R.layout.apero_detail_layout, aperoList);
     //   final ListView list = (ListView)root.findViewById(R.id.list_apero);
     //    list.setAdapter(adapter);

        return root;
    }

    private void initList(ArrayList<AperoVersion> androidList) {
...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems is the following line

```
transaction.replace(R.id.list_apero, newFragment);
```

You're trying to create a fragment transaction using your listView's ID.

Do this inside your `Fragment Resource file` where your list view is, add an id called `content`(or any other name) to your layout like this`android:id="@+id/content"`

then in the code where your are doing your fragment replacement, edit this line of code `transaction.replace(R.id.list_apero, nextFrag);` to be `transaction.replace(R.id.content, nextFrag);`

Comment: I don't get the difference between using my `list_apero` id (it's where I want to place the new fragment) and `content` could you explain me ?

Comment: Because, it's not possible to create a fragment transaction and use your listview as container for the fragment you want to add.  Take a look at this tutorial from android developer page  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui

Comment: ideally you should have a framelayout and then use that framelayout for your fragment's transactions

Comment: Okay now I have the 2 fragment one on each other, I can't figure out how to remove the first one